# Spring validation with hibernate validator not finding validation errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Intended function: My website form should redirect to the form processed page if the last name has a length of greater than one. If not, it should redirect the user back to the login page.
The error: When the last name field has less than 1 character, I still get redirected to the form processed page.

Customer class:

```
package com.example.springvalidation.model;


import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Customer {
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message="This field is required")
    @Size(min=1, message="length must be greater than 1")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
package com.example.springvalidation.controllers;

import com.example.springvalidation.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView displayForm(ModelAndView mv) {
       mv.addObject("customer", new Customer());
       mv.setViewName("customer-form");

       return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
                                    BindingResult br) {
        if (br.hasErrors()) {
            return "customer-form";
        }
        return "form-processed";

    }
}
```

customer-form.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer registration form</title>

    <style>
        .error {color:red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">

        First name: <form:input path="firstName"/>

        <br><br>

        Last name*: <form:input path="lastName"/>
        <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

form-processed.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Customer processed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Customer successfully processed!</h1>
        <hr>
        <h2>Customer info:</h2>
        <p1>
            Customer first name: ${customer.firstName}
            <br><br>
            Customer last name: ${customer.lastName}
        </p1>
    </body>
</html>
```

My libraries:

[image: Libraries]

Answer (score 0):

Add `GroupSequence` to validate `lastName` not empty and length check.

**Step1:** First create two interfaces as `FirstValidation.class` and `SecondValidation.class`

```
public interface FirstValidation
{
}

public interface SecondValidation
{
}
```

**Step2:** Then Create `GroupSequence` interface as follows.

```
@GroupSequence({ FirstValidation.class, SecondValidation.class })
public interface OrderedCheck
{
}
```

**Step3:** Don't use `@NotNull` for the check string is empty. Use `@NotBlank`. It is more appropriate. And add groups like this.

```
@NotBlank(groups = {FirstValidation.class} , message="This field is required")
@Size(min=1, groups = {SecondValidation.class} , message="length must be greater than 1")
private String lastName;
```

**Step4:** Finally change your controller method as follows. Note: Use `@Validated` instead of `@Valid`

```
@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm(@Validated({OrderedCheck.class})  @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
                                BindingResult br) {
    if (br.hasErrors()) {
        return "customer-form";
    }
    return "form-processed";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer however this hasn't solved my problem. Shouldn't the validation still work without the OrderedCheck